# Set environment variables to devtools::check() when doing CTRL+SHIFT+E in RStudio

Tags: r

I would like to set environment variables when checking my package by `CTRL + SHIFT + E`.

`devtools::check(remote = FALSE)` does what I want, as well as `R CMD check` with environnment variable *R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE*=false (I guess)

I only managed to put R CMD CHECK options (--as-cran...) into the project options, not environment variables...